# Symfony - Categories count with EntityType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have a search form that gets Categories from database and shows each category name as a checkbox, it's retrieved via EntityType, i want to show count categories in front of the category name, i managed to count each one from the database and put the result in an array like this : $categCount[name] = count;

**How can i show in front of each category name her count using EntityType ?**

```
->add('categories', EntityType::class, ['class' => 'AppBundle:Categorie',
                                                   'choice_label' => 'name',
                                                   'multiple' => true,
                                                   'expanded' => true,
                                                   'required' => false,
        ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now. I`m not sure how your entity looks like but if you have the count in the same entity you can do something like:

```
->add('categories', EntityType::class, ['class' => 'AppBundle:Categorie',
                                                   'choice_label' => 'getNameWithCategoriesCount',
                                                   'multiple' => true,
                                                   'expanded' => true,
                                                   'required' => false,
        ])
```

and in your entity

```
public function getNameWithCategoriesCount(){
    return $this->getName().' '.$this->getCount();
}
```

Alternatively(not tested) you can :

```
     ->add(
            'categories',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Categorie',

                'choice_label' => function ($category) use ($this-em) {
                    return $category->getDisplayName() $this->em->getRepo..()->getCount($category);
                },
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        )
```

NOTE: For this approach you need to declare your form as service and pass the entityManager

Comment: cool, didn't know that was possible, thanks a lot.  do you know how i can access the repository inside my entity, so i can implement the $ this-> getCount () method ?

Comment: While possible (set entity as service and inject the entity manager in the constructor ) its a bad practice to have entity manager in the entity. I would recommend to have the count data in the same entity. You can set a crone job to update the count property using custom console command docs here https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#main

Comment: i want to keep my project as simple as possible